# What is best task processing algorithm where multiple users adds tasks to queue?

Tags: algorithm, queue, task

I am designing a system in which multiple users will add tasks to the table, each task consumes an equal amount of time. I am currently using a FIFO system, but it is causing problems when users add hundreds of tasks in one go. This results in delays for other users who have a small no of tasks.

Please suggest algorithms so that each user in the queue gets equal processing time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do it like this:

- Instead of putting tasks directly into the work queue, make a separate task queue for each user.  Each request puts a task into its user's queue, and when the user queue goes from empty to non-empty, *put the user queue into the global work queue*
- Workers take user queues from the work queue when they are ready for more work.  When a worker takes a user queue, it takes out the first task and *the worker immediately puts the user queue back at the end of the work queue if it's not empty*.  Then the worker performs the task.

Using this system, each user queue is in the work queue at most once, and  *all users with associated work are equally represented in the work queue*.

This is pretty easy to implement, but you do have to be careful about detecting when you have to put an user queue into the work queue, since there can be two threads making this decision at the same time, and you don't want the user queue to go in twice.

I make it simple like this:

- Have an atomic Boolean in each user queue that keeps track of whether or not it's in the work queue. The worker sets this to false immediately after dequeing the user queue. If anyone finds the user queue non-empty, they can try to CAS this boolean to true, and if successful put the user queue into the work queue.
- There's a small chance that a user queue could get into the work queue when it's empty.  Make sure this is harmless -- if a worker fails to take a task from a user queue, it should just forget about it and take a new user queue from the work queue.